# How to activate keyword highlighting in search results of DuckDuckGo?

Tags: search, search-engine, duckduckgo, keyword, highlight

Is it possible to have the query words highlighted in the search results of DuckDuckGo? I really like the Google layout, which displays text passages with query word in bold fonts. Does DDG have a similar feature?

Comment: No one? Anyone?